# Python players bet

Tags: python

**I have the following code:**

```
numplayers=int(input('Enter number of players  here: '))
numcoins=int(input('Enter number of coins per player  here: '))

for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    print('Player',x,'has',numcoins,'coins')

bank_amount=int(input('Please enter the bank amount here: '))
bet=int(input('Please enter the bet per player here: '))
player_bet=[]
for i in range(1,numplayers+2):
    player_bet.append(bet)
for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    print('Player',x,'has bet',player_bet[x])
```

**and the result of the above code is, for example:**

```
Enter number of players  here: 4
Enter number of coins per player  here: 5
Player 1 has 5 coins
Player 2 has 5 coins
Player 3 has 5 coins
Player 4 has 5 coins
Please enter the bank amount here: 15
Please enter the bet per player here: 5
Player 1 has bet 5
Player 2 has bet 5
Player 3 has bet 5
Player 4 has bet 5
```

*The problem here is that I want this code to do this:*

- lets take the example above where bank amount is 15 and the players bet is 5
- I want this program to stop when the bank amount equals the player bet
- in other words in the above example player 4 should not have any ability to bet

**Any ideas on how I can achieve the above?**

Comment: What have you tried so far and why isn't it working? Hint: can you find a way to print the total player bets after each player enters their bet? Do you know how to compare this amount to the amount in the bank?

Comment: Check (if-statement) in the "bet"-loop if the `bank_amount` is bigger than a single bet, if it's the case than subtract the bet value from `bank_amount`and append the bet to your list, if it is not the case then break the loop with the keyword `break`. And have a look at your for-loops, consider to use `enumerate` instead of `range` in your for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
player_bet=[]
for i in range(1,numplayers+2):
    if sum(player_bet) == bank_amount:
        break 
    player_bet.append(bet)
for x in range(1,numplayers+1):
    if sum(player_bet) == bank_amount:
        break 
    print('Player',x,'has bet',player_bet[x])
```